# views exposed filters - return user selection or another value

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type with multiple fields and a view to display them. I have an exposed filter for one of the fields and want to achieve this functionality:

when a user select a value for this filter I want to return those nodes but also the ones that have a certain value on another field.

Is there any way I can achieve that from the interface? I know how to do it with [hook_views_query_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to do but hard to find the answer.

In the views's `FILTER CRITERIA` click the down pointing arrow and select the second option (`and/or, rearrange`). Then create a new filter group and play around with the options there :)